# Why is br_table in devtools different than the wast examples and how does it work?

Tags: webassembly

I was looking at the br_table examples from the WebAssembly test suite but they don't look like the ones I'm seeing in devtools. For example, this is a random br_table I picked from wast `(br_table 0 1 2 (i32.const 16) (local.get 0))`
But I'm looking at some WebAssembly pages with devtools and br_table looks like this in them
`br_table $label94 $label95 $label96 $label86`. It also appears to randomly repeat the labels a lot, like `br_table $label102 $label103 $label103 $label103 $label104 $label103`. For some reason it just uses $label103 a ton.

I tried looking at documentation for br_table but I didn't find anything at all. I also tried checking some ideas I had for what it could be but to no avail. Could someone please explain how this works?